# Why am I not getting a Buffer Overflow?

Tags: c, stack-overflow

Everything I read leads me to believe that this should cause a [stack buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow), but it does not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char password[8];
    int correctPassword = 0;

    printf("Password \n");
    gets(password);

    if(strcmp(password, "password"))
    {
        printf ("Wrong password entered, root privileges not granted... \n");
    }
    else
    {
        correctPassword = 1;
    }

    if(correctPassword)
    {
        printf ("Root privileges given to the user \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But here is my output:

[image: description]

in this case, testtesttesttesttest is clearly larger than 8 characters, and, according to the [source](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/buffer-overflow/?utm_source=feedly), it should cause a [stack buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow), but it does not. Why is this?

Comment: Because it's undefined behavior, so anything could happen. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior#t=201706020423447810219.

Comment: How exactly do you expect the stack overflow to manifest? When I run this I get the following output: `Wrong password entered, root privileges not granted... 
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./Overflow terminated
`

Comment: What do `p &password[8]` and `p &correctPassword` show?

Comment: @merlin2011: If you compile it without stack protection it has a better chance of working.

Comment: password shows testtest and correctPassword is 0, as seen above

Comment: There is no such thing as 'stack buffer overflow'. There is 'stack overflow', and 'buffer overflow'. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Ahh. got it. I needed to add -fno-stack-protector to get the program to not print `*** stack smashing detected ***` and instead fill correctPassword with the overflowed bytes. Thanks @Ryan

Comment: @StanleyCupPhil: You missed the `&`s.

Comment: @EJP Seems a wikipedia article dedicated to [Stack Buffer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) ;)

Comment: @EJP I think the disambiguation here is "stack 'buffer overflow'" vs "heap 'buffer overflow'"  ie the buffer that overflows is on the stack rather than the heap. This is different to a stack overflow whereby the stack pointer advances past it's allowed range.

Comment: I've edited the OP to link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow and replaced "stack overflow" in the text to "stack buffer overflow" to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading more bytes then your buffer can contain won't always lead to a run-time error but it's a very bad and common error (read this article [about smashing the stack](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)). As I read from comments you added *-fno-stack-protector to get the program to not print* *** stack smashing detected *** but that's not a good idea. You should use `scanf(" %8s",password)` or something similar to limit the dimension of what you read.

Comment: A [Stack Buffer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) is indeed a thing as apposed to a [heap buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_overflow)

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I don't get where I'm talking about heap. Can you be more specific?

Comment: You criticized the term "Stack buffer overflow" for being an incorrect term claiming it different to a "buffer overflow". There is nothing wrong with the term "stack buffer overflow". It means precisely a buffer that exists on the stack which has been written to but outside it's bounds.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I'm so sorry, you're right. I just misreading it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does cause a buffer overflow on the stack, in the sense that you have overwritten the allocated memory for the `password` buffer. Behold the memory that has been overwritten after you provide the input.

```
gcc -o Overflow Overflow.c -fno-stack-protector -g

gdb Overflow
(gdb) b 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005cc: file Overflow.c, line 8.
(gdb) b 11
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4005e2: file Overflow.c, line 11.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/hq6/Code/SO/C/Overflow

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde08) at Overflow.c:8
8       printf("Password \n");
(gdb) x/20x password
# Memory before overflow
0x7fffffffdd10: 0xffffde00  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffdd20: 0x00400630  0x00000000  0xf7a2e830  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffdd30: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffde08  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffdd40: 0xf7ffcca0  0x00000001  0x004005b6  0x00000000
0x7fffffffdd50: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x67fbace7  0x593e0a93
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Password
correctPassword

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde08) at Overflow.c:11
11      if(strcmp(password, "password"))
(gdb) x/20x password
# Memory after overflow
0x7fffffffdd10: 0x72726f63  0x50746365  0x77737361  0x0064726f
0x7fffffffdd20: 0x00400630  0x00000000  0xf7a2e830  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffdd30: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffde08  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffdd40: 0xf7ffcca0  0x00000001  0x004005b6  0x00000000
0x7fffffffdd50: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x67fbace7  0x593e0a93
```

Whether or not a buffer overflow has undesirable side effects is undefined behavior.